# How would a WHEN condition work in a JOIN query?

Tags: mysql, sql

Where's the problem in this query?
I can't figure out a way to make it work.
I need to select just the 'ricette' with id = 4 and then join with the other table 'val'. I don't know where to put the WHERE condition 'WHERE ric.id = 4'. Without 'WHERE ric.id = 4' the query works, but obviously it returns me all the values in the table 'ricette' and not just the 'ricette.id = 4'.

This is the query:

```
SELECT * FROM ricette AS ric WHERE ric.id = 4 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT id_ricetta, AVG(valutazione) AS media
FROM `valutazioni` GROUP BY id_ricetta) AS val ON ric.id = val.id_ricetta
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JOIN` is an *operator* not a clause in SQL.  It is only recognized in the `FROM` clause.

It operates on tables/derived tables/views.  So, your query should be written with the `LEFT JOIN` in the `FROM` clause:

```
SELECT *
FROM ricette AS ric LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT id_ricetta, AVG(valutazione) AS media
      FROM `valutazioni`
      GROUP BY id_ricetta
     ) AS val
     ON ric.id = val.id_ricetta
WHERE ric.id = 4 ;
```

You will note that when I write code, if an expression with an operator spans more than one line, I put the operator at the end of the line.  To me, this makes it clear that the expression spans multiple lines.

On the other hand, I left align the *clauses* in a SQL query.  These are generally:  `SELECT`, `FROM`, `WHERE`, `GROUP BY`, `HAVING`, and `ORDER BY`.

As a note, the following is a more performant version of your query:

```
SELECT r.*,
       (SELECT AVG(v.valutazione)
        FROM valutazioni v
        WHERE v.id_ricetta = r.id
       ) as media
FROM ricette r
WHERE ric.id = 4 ;
```

The reason for this is simple.  You are filtering the results in the query.  However, your version is aggregating *all* of `valutazationi` -- which is (presumably) much more data and just `id = 4`.  An index on `valutazioni(id_ricetta, valutazione)` would speed it up even more.